# String to 2D Slice

Tags: go, slice

I receive from a Redis store a 2D array as string:

```
func main() {
    client := setRedisClient()
    data, err := client.Get(redisKey).Result()
    // store data as a 2D slice
}
```

Here is an example of what data might look like:

```
[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a 2D slice since I need to be able to use indices:

```
dataAsSlice := [][]string {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}} 
fmt.Println(dataAsSlice[0][0]) => "a"
```

I haven't found a way to parse a response from redis and store is as a 2D slice.

How could I achieve this? Is even storing is as a 2D slice the best way?

Comment: If the string you get from Redis is a JSON array of JSON arrays of strings just unmarsahl that into a slice of slice of strings and you are good.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your string is JSON, you can convert it to a `[][]string{}` by using `json.Unmarshal` as follows:

```
str := `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]`
var dataAsSlice [][]string
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &dataAsSlice)
```

You can see this in action on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NEpIKc9Fl-s